# How to migrate a legacy a DOMContentLoaded function inside a Vue 3 component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm trying to refactor a website inside a Vue 3 single page app.
Everything is working but I cannot understand which is the best way to insert and execute some javascript functions...

In my homepage, that now is a component, I use this function to create a parallax star + mountain landscape

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  (function() {
    var requestAnimationFrame = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || function(callback) {
      window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
    };
    window.requestAnimationFrame = requestAnimationFrame;
  })();

  // Terrain stuff.
  var background = document.getElementById("bg-canvas")
  var backgroundHome = document.getElementById("bg-home")
  var bgCtx = background.getContext("2d"),
    width = window.innerWidth,
    height = window.innerHeight;


  (height < 400) ? height = 400: height;

  background.width = width;
  background.height = height;

  function Terrain(options) {
    options = options || {};
    this.terrain = document.createElement("canvas");
    this.terCtx = this.terrain.getContext("2d");
    this.scrollDelay = options.scrollDelay || 90;
    this.lastScroll = new Date().getTime();

    this.terrain.width = width;
    this.terrain.height = height;
    this.fillStyle = options.fillStyle || "#494776";
    this.mHeight = options.mHeight || height;

    // generate
    this.points = [];

    var displacement = options.displacement || 140,
      power = Math.pow(2, Math.ceil(Math.log(width) / (Math.log(2))));

    // set the start height and end height for the terrain
    this.points[0] = this.mHeight; //(this.mHeight - (Math.random() * this.mHeight / 2)) - displacement;
    this.points[power] = this.points[0];

    // create the rest of the points
    for (var i = 1; i < power; i *= 2) {
      for (var j = (power / i) / 2; j < power; j += power / i) {
        this.points[j] = ((this.points[j - (power / i) / 2] + this.points[j + (power / i) / 2]) / 2) + Math.floor(Math.random() * -displacement + displacement);
      }
      displacement *= 0.6;
    }

    background.after(this.terrain);
  }

  Terrain.prototype.update = function() {
    // draw the terrain
    this.terCtx.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
    this.terCtx.fillStyle = this.fillStyle;

    if (new Date().getTime() > this.lastScroll + this.scrollDelay) {
      this.lastScroll = new Date().getTime();
      this.points.push(this.points.shift());
    }

    this.terCtx.beginPath();
    for (var i = 0; i <= width; i++) {
      if (i === 0) {
        this.terCtx.moveTo(0, this.points[0]);
      } else if (this.points[i] !== undefined) {
        this.terCtx.lineTo(i, this.points[i]);
      }
    }

    this.terCtx.lineTo(width, this.terrain.height);
    this.terCtx.lineTo(0, this.terrain.height);
    this.terCtx.lineTo(0, this.points[0]);
    this.terCtx.fill();
  }


  // Second canvas used for the stars
  bgCtx.fillStyle = '#05004c';
  bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);

  // stars
  function Star(options) {
    this.size = Math.random() * 2;
    this.speed = Math.random() * .05;
    this.x = options.x;
    this.y = options.y;
  }

  Star.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.size = Math.random() * 2;
    this.speed = Math.random() * .05;
    this.x = width;
    this.y = Math.random() * height;
  }

  Star.prototype.update = function() {
    this.x -= this.speed;
    if (this.x < 0) {
      this.reset();
    } else {
      bgCtx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    }
  }

  function ShootingStar() {
    this.reset();
  }

  ShootingStar.prototype.reset = function() {
    this.x = Math.random() * width;
    this.y = 0;
    this.len = (Math.random() * 80) + 10;
    this.speed = (Math.random() * 10) + 6;
    this.size = (Math.random() * 1) + 0.1;
    // this is used so the shooting stars arent constant
    this.waitTime = new Date().getTime() + (Math.random() * 3000) + 500;
    this.active = false;
  }

  ShootingStar.prototype.update = function() {
    if (this.active) {
      this.x -= this.speed;
      this.y += this.speed;
      if (this.x < 0 || this.y >= height) {
        this.reset();
      } else {
        bgCtx.lineWidth = this.size;
        bgCtx.beginPath();
        bgCtx.moveTo(this.x, this.y);
        bgCtx.lineTo(this.x + this.len, this.y - this.len);
        bgCtx.stroke();
      }
    } else {
      if (this.waitTime < new Date().getTime()) {
        this.active = true;
      }
    }
  }

  var entities = [];

  // init the stars
  for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
    entities.push(new Star({
      x: Math.random() * width,
      y: Math.random() * height
    }));
  }

  // Add 2 shooting stars that just cycle.
  entities.push(new ShootingStar());
  entities.push(new ShootingStar());
  entities.push(new Terrain({
    displacement: 150,
    scrollDelay: 20,
    fillStyle: "#221445",
    mHeight: height / 2
  }));
  entities.push(new Terrain({
    displacement: 120,
    scrollDelay: 50,
    fillStyle: "#2e1f56",
    mHeight: (height / 2) - 30
  }));
  entities.push(new Terrain({
    mHeight: (height / 2) - 60
  }));

  //animate background
  function animate() {
    bgCtx.fillStyle = '#055e8f';
    bgCtx.fillRect(0, 0, width, height);
    bgCtx.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    bgCtx.strokeStyle = '#ffffff';

    var entLen = entities.length;

    while (entLen--) {
      entities[entLen].update();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
  }
  animate();

});
```

Which is the most efficient way to execute this when my homepage component is mounted?

Comment: A correct way is to do this in onMounted hook. Refer to DOM elements as refs and not `document` selectors. Make a cleanup in onUnmounted to avoid memory leaks. It doesn't make sense to define classes inside a function because they are supposed to be reused

Comment: You are right, but in this case I don't think I will reuse this classes. This is just an animation I need for the home...

Comment: You will reuse these classes between different component instances. You asked about efficiency. It's efficient to not declare something on each call if you can avoid this.